# read only text box if data is not preloaded

Tags: javascript, html, grails, gsp

I have a screen which will be loaded dynamically along with countries,text boxes with some preloaded data and revert button next to them.

I would like to make the text boxes readonly/disabled if they are not having any preloaded data and not to show the button next to them.

Please let me know how it can be done.

Comment: How exactly are you loading the values? By JSP or JavaScript? You've both tags on the question but you didn't provide any details about the code, which thus makes your whole question pretty ambiguous and unanswerable.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, its actually gsp(grails) along with some javascript. values are being loaded from database. is there any feature of the text box tag to check if its having data, if not, need to make it readonly

Comment: Uh yes, but **who** is responsible for preloading and filling the fields? If it were JavaScript, then you can only solve it with another JavaScript. If it were JSP, then you can solve it with both JSP and JavaScript (but preferably JSP only). In any way, I've replaced the JSP tag by Grails/GSP tags as you seem to be actually using them.

Comment: yeah it should be combination of js and jsp, do you have any idea on how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

When you get the input check if the textbox has a value if it doesn't make a call to a javascript method such as the on below.

```
document.forms['myFormId'].myTextArea.setAttribute('readonly','readonly');
```

i'm not sure about the disable of the button but if I had to take a guess I would when you are checking the input value if there is data display button otherwise skip

Answer (score 0):

and disabled properties of text box, resolved my issue along with below code

Comment: <g:if test="${'usercannoteditthisurl'.equals(temp.get(country.key))}">